# Propel data from Joined tables not available

Tags: php, mysql, propel

I'm trying to show the first image of an imagealbum in a list. But when creating a query i cannot access the $album->getImageuri() method in the foreach loop.

```
$albums = \ApAlbumQuery::create()
            ->join('ApAlbum.ApAlbumImage', \Propel\Runtime\ActiveQuery\Criteria::LEFT_JOIN)
            ->join('ApAlbumImage.ApImage', \Propel\Runtime\ActiveQuery\Criteria::LEFT_JOIN)
            ->where('ApAlbum.visibility is not null')
            ->groupBy('ApAlbum.Id')
            ->orderByStartdate("ASC")
            ->find();

foreach($albums as $album)
{
    echo $album->getImageuri(); // not working?
}
```

When running the sql-query created with the Propel ->toString() method everything is present.

Anybody know what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: What do you get when you `print_r($album);` instead of `echo ...`?

Comment: Then i get exactly the same if i would select all the albums without the join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the `ImageURI` column using `->withColumn()`:

```
$albums = \ApAlbumQuery::create()
        ->join('ApAlbum.ApAlbumImage', \Propel\Runtime\ActiveQuery\Criteria::LEFT_JOIN)
        ->join('ApAlbumImage.ApImage', \Propel\Runtime\ActiveQuery\Criteria::LEFT_JOIN)
        ->withColumn('ApAlbumImage.ApImage.ImageURI')
        ->where('ApAlbum.visibility is not null')
        ->groupBy('ApAlbum.Id')
        ->orderByStartdate("ASC")
        ->find();

foreach($albums as $album)
{
    echo $album->getImageuri(); // not working?
}
```

From your `->join()` syntax, I assume that your're using different schemata

Comment: Hi, Your anwser worked but instead of "ApAlbumImage.ApImage.ImageURI" you only need "ImageURI" otherwise you get an error. Thanks!

Comment: Oh yes, that was a lucky guess since I don't an idea of what your DB structure looks like